# Search and delete a particular track in iTunes using Applescript

Tags: applescript, itunes

I am using iTunes to convert a large .aif file to a much smaller .mp3 file. The filename changes each day because I am adding the date to the name. So, a file named "abcxyz 2-2-2014" gets converted in iTunes. After the conversion, I want to delete it from iTunes. I'm trying to use Applescript to search for the file and delete it. I'm trying this:

```
on deleteTrack(trackName)
tell application "iTunes"
    set theTrack to track named trackName of playlist "Library"
    set songFile to location of theTrack
    delete theTrack
end tell
tell application "Finder" to delete songFile
end deleteTrack

on run
   tell application "iTunes"
        set result to (file tracks whose name contains "abcxyz")
        repeat with t in result
            deleteTrack(name of t as string)
        end repeat
   end tell
end run
```

I found the deleteTrack routine which works perfectly if you pass it a string like this:

```
on run
   deleteTrack("abcxyz 2-2-2014")
end run
```

But that requires that I know the exact name of the track, which I don't. The error that I get is "Can't continue deleteTrack" ..with the deleteTrack(name of t as string) line selected in Applescript Editor.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You should re-read the material about AppleScript's handlers. Because your handler call is inside of a tell application "iTunes" block, AppleScript is looking in iTunes for deleteTrack. Try this instead:

```
my deleteTrack(name of t as string)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Accept my answer by clicking the check mark so other users know your issue is resolved.